# How to get list of files for a commit in Atlassian SourceTree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm in the Log view.  I think I'm missing detail in the bottom pane when I click on a commit/branch.

I want this (found on sourcetreeapp website):
[image]

This is what I currently see:
[image]

I'm missing the bottom-left panel.  Where did it go?

Answer (score 3):

The bottom-left panel is still there, but for some reason it's collapsed into a width of zero pixels. I noticed that if you move the mouse very carefully, the cursor will change from a double-arrow divider to a single-arrow divider pointing to the right. Drag and drop it in this state and the panel shall be restored.

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac you can delete the following defaults instead of nuking your entire configuration:

```
defaults delete com.torusknot.SourceTreeNotMAS "NSSplitView Subview Frames repowindow_LogViewLowerSplitter"
defaults delete com.torusknot.SourceTreeNotMAS "NSSplitView Subview Frames repowindow_LogViewDescSplitter"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just [resetting my configurations](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/SOURCETREEKB/Wiping+SourceTree+Preferences) and it now works.  :\